# Django admin on adding a new FK show in modal instead of a popup

Tags: django, django-admin

Hello I am wondering how to make the add_form to show in modal instead of a popup when adding a new foreign key instance of a field in the django admin.

Explanation.

When pressing the + button on FK I want the form in a modal instead of a popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently possible with django admin. You could implement it yourself, but you would need to:

1) write the code for the modal with the form that you want yourself, you'd also need to handle

2) Then extend the original template to open the modal, handle the requests etc, update or reload the original page.

Tbh, it would be far more effort than it's worth for something cosmetic like a modal. I'm sorry that this probably isn't the answer you're after, but it really won't be worth the hours that it would require to make this happen :(

If it's really critical that you need a modal for this, you probably shouldn't be using the admin site at all (it's not designed to be a production ready site).

Comment: that's what I did :D apparently no easy way